# dir lists up until filenames starting with "c" then says file not found

Tags: filesystems, windows-xp, cmd, dir

I have a computer that does not show all of the files in windows explorer or when doing a dir from command line.  When browsing in windows explorer - it goes up until file "cat.doc" then no more. If I do a dir in my documents - it will list until it gets to "cat.doc" and then next line says "File Not Found".

If I go to microsoft word- and type the filename exactly of a file not shown - it will open.  Example - "Dog.doc" will open in word if I type the filename in the open file dialog box even though it doesn't show in windows explorer or the dir command.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Not that likely, but possible: corrupted file system. Did you try running CHKDSK for that partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out - a chkdsk was able to fix the problems in just a short amount of time.  It spit out two lines saying repaired index - didn't write down exactly what it said.  However, when logged in - it was working properly again.  Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

One problem that fits symptoms like these is the presence of a file with one of the [names reserved by Windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/10/22/55388.aspx): `CON`, `NUL`, `AUX`, and so on.  In this case, `CON` might explain why it cuts off at the letter C.  You might experiment with creating files called `COM` and `COO` and see if the cutoff happens right between them.

If there is indeed a file called `CON` in your directory, you can delete it following the advice on [Server Fault #282194](https://superuser.com/questions/282194/how-do-i-remove-a-file-named-nul-on-windows):

```
Del \\?\C:\Your\Directory\CON
```

Comment: DIR seems to be fine about displaying files that have reserved names. Still, I find your answer useful for myself and have upvoted it as such.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I did a chkdsk and that seemed for fix the problem.